# Dimension filter not working on visual object

Tags: powerbi, dax, dimension

I have a dimension filter on a visual which doesn't work. The table consist three dimensions:

[image]

The measure I use in the visual are as follows:

```
Chat 2022 = CALCULATE(SUM('LD Henvendelser kanaler'[Value]), 'LD Henvendelser kanaler'[Kanal]="Chat" && 'LD Henvendelser kanaler'[Year]=2022)
```

And the same goes for the other dimensions

The slicer filter I am using on the visual object contains the field "Kanal", but it does not work. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use KEEPFILTERS like:

```
Chat 2022 = CALCULATE(SUM('LD Henvendelser kanaler'[Value]), KEEPFILTERS('LD Henvendelser kanaler'[Kanal]="Chat" && 'LD Henvendelser kanaler'[Year]=2022))
```

Why? See bullets 2 & 3 in Remarks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/keepfilters-function-dax